# Debian : any downsides of totally replacing /etc/apt/sources.list by /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some_equivalent_files.list?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

We have set up an local apt repository cache server, we thus have began to automate the setup of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/our_custom_files.list` of our Debian 10+11+12 machines.

This lead us to wonder if we could legitimately totally delete the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, in favour of putting its equivalent content into our custom `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/our_files.list` files?

Are their any requirements stating that this file must exist or any automation we might break doing so?

So far, we saw nothing wrong but before spreading this to a lot of servers, I was wondering if some trouble could be expected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not aware of any requirement that `sources.list` exist. In fact, current cloud images for Debian 12 don’t ship one; instead, they ship a “Deb822” style file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources`:

```
Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
Suites: bookworm bookworm-updates
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security
Suites: bookworm-security
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```

You might find [this format](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/sources.list.5#DEB822-STYLE_FORMAT) useful for your own automation...