# Sources.list file is missing in debian12 docker image

Tags: linux, debian, docker

I have a Dockerfile that uses `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0` to build one .net8 C# app.
Previously that Dockerfile was using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0`
Inside I have a command `RUN sed -i -e's/ main/ main contrib/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`.
When I try to build the image in gives me an error

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sed -i -e's/ main/ main contrib/g' /etc/apt/sources.list" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

the inner error is:

```
#11 [ 7/18] RUN sed -i -e's/ main/ main contrib/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
#11 0.249 sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory
```

I saw that `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` is based on Debian 11, and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0` in based on Debian 12, so I pulled the two docker images on my pc and run both containers.

On the one with Debian 11 I have `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but on the Debian 12 one I do not have it:

Debian 11:
[image]

Debian 12:
[image]

Is there something that I do wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

Regards, Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 12 images don’t ship an `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, they use file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` instead, [`debian.sources`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/759806/86440).

Answer (score 0):

Try `RUN sed -i 's/^Components: main$/& contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources`